# Removing string from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please see below data..

Table A

```
AID        NAME
1          A
2          B
3          C
4          D
5          E
6          F
```

Table B

```
BID        AID        NAME

1          1          T1
2          1          T2
3          2          T3
4          2          T4
5          3          T5
6          4          T6
7          1          T7
8          1          T8
9          2          T9
10         2          T10
11         3          T11
12         4          T12
```

I am using this statement

```
SELECT 
    dbo.A.NAME AS ANAME, dbo.B.NAME AS BNAME
FROM   
    dbo.A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.B ON dbo.A.AID = dbo.B.AID
```

Its returning these results:

```
ANAME          BNAME
A           T1        
A           T2        
A           T7        
A           T8        
B           T3        
B           T4        
B           T9        
B           T10       
C           T5        
C           T11       
D           T6        
D           T12       
E           NULL
F           NULL
```

but I need following result

```
ANAME       BNAME
A           T1        
            T2        
            T7        
            T8        
B           T3        
            T4        
            T9        
            T10       
C           T5        
            T11       
D           T6        
            T12       
E           NULL
F           NULL
```

How to remove extra names from above?

Comment: That's a presentation issue, nothing you do in SQL.

Comment: Essentially you have to do this in server side code, otherwise you may not have relation between 'ANAME' and 'BNAME'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY A.NAME ORDER BY A.NAME ) = 1
             THEN A.NAME
             ELSE ''
        END AS ANAME ,
        dbo.B.NAME AS BNAME
FROM    dbo.A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.B ON dbo.A.AID = dbo.B.AID;
```

Comment: how do you sort that?

Comment: @Aツ: What do you mean by sort "that" ??

Comment: i do not see any `order by `which means sql is free to deliver the rows in any order and since the column `aname`is blank its not possible to sort the result by `aname, bname`

Comment: @Aツ: From the query provided by OP, i have made this query. Another thing as per the data provided in question `a.name` is never null. second thing i have not done sorting on `b.name`. I have not write `order by..` clause at the end because its upto the user in which order he wants the result. Main point is OP got the expected output. :)

Comment: @Aツ I dont need sort. as per asnwer my requirement full fill

Comment: @KrishnrajRana I dont need sort. as per asnwer my requirement full fill

Comment: @KrishnrajRana sql is free to deliver the rows in any order unless you specify an `order by` which means the output could be sorted by `bname` or in any random order.

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like the following could be done if absolutely needed to do in SQL, seeing as it is presentation.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY A.AID ORDER BY A.AID ) > 1
             THEN ''
             ELSE A.NAME
        END AS ANAME ,
        dbo.B.NAME AS BNAME
FROM    dbo.A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.B ON dbo.A.AID = dbo.B.AID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below SQL query to get your desired output:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN SrNo = 1 
            THEN ANAME
            ELSE ''
            END) AS ANAME
        , BNAME
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.A.NAME ORDER BY dbo.B.NAME) AS SrNo, 
           dbo.A.NAME AS ANAME, dbo.B.NAME AS BNAME
    FROM   dbo.A LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.B ON dbo.A.AID = dbo.B.AID
) AS tbl
```